# POSTing a JSON array on Node Destroys the structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, parsing

The JSON object that I am POSTing is losing its array structure when it hits the Node JS body-parser.

I am Posting a JSON object with the following structure:

```
{

FirstName: "Name",
LastName: "Name",

Cars: [

  {

     Make: "Ford",
     Model: "Mustang"

  }

]
```

However when the Node JS backend calls req.body object I get:

```
{
"FirstName":"Name",
"LastName":"Name",
"Cars[0][Make]":"Ford",
"Cars[0][Model]":"Mustang"
}
```

Any reason this does not come over as a JSON with a array of objects that I can parse?

Comment: Are you **sure** that's the syntax you used? Because `Cars` looks like a computed property syntax in ES6 (hint: the missing `:`)

Comment: You are correct I typed it wrong, fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had something similar today sendign with JSON.stringify sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

You have to include contentType in the ajax call and call JSON.stringify on the data before sending

```
$.ajax({ url: "/home/save_userdata/",
     type: "POST", 
     contentType: 'application/json', 
     data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Thanks to Dan Kudia for pointing me in the right dirction